# What is the behavior of document.createElement when passed as an argument?

Tags: javascript, dom

When attempting to pass an element created by the `document.createElement` method, we encounter unusual results:

```js
var Todo = (function () {
  return {
    items: [],
    addItem: function () {
      var task = document
        .querySelector('#top-todo')
        .value
        .trim()
      if (task !== '') {
        this.items.push({ task, complete: false })
        document.querySelector('#top-todo').value = ''
        console.log('Added item: ' + task)
        var newTodo = document.createElement('li')
          .appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
          .appendChild(document.createTextNode(task))
        document.querySelector('#todo-list').appendChild(newTodo)
      }
    }
  }
})()
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="todo-list">
    <li>
      <input id="top-todo" placeholder="I need to..." type="text" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input onclick="Todo.addItem()" type="button" value="add" />
</div>
```

Rather than a total failure or typeError we see only the textNode element being appended to the `#todo-list` element. What is the cause of this behavior? And is there a valid way to use the method as an argument to append or insert?

Comment: @charlietfl i'm not sure how you mean.

Comment: Don't treat the DOM API as fluent/chainable. They're not designed to be chainable. If you want chaining use jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

> The returned value is the appended child.

You can chain `.parentElement.parentElement`, the number of nested elements set as child elements of `li`, to last `.appendChild()` call to get reference to `document.createElement('li')` at `newTodo`

```js
var Todo = (function () {
  return {
    items: [],
    addItem: function () {
      var task = document
        .querySelector('#top-todo')
        .value
        .trim()
      if (task !== '') {
        this.items.push({ task, complete: false })
        document.querySelector('#top-todo').value = ''
        console.log('Added item: ' + task)
        var newTodo = document.createElement('li')
          .appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
          .appendChild(document.createTextNode(task))
          .parentElement.parentElement                    
        document.querySelector('#todo-list').appendChild(newTodo)
      }
    }
  }
})()
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="todo-list">
    <li>
      <input id="top-todo" placeholder="I need to..." type="text" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input onclick="Todo.addItem()" type="button" value="add" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newTodo = document.createElement('li')
  .appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
  .appendChild(document.createTextNode(task))
```

[`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) returns the element that was appended. When you chain functions, you get the last returned value in the chain.

It goes kinda like this:

1. Create `li` (`li` is current working value)
2. Create `p`
3. Append `p` to `li` (`p` is current working value)
4. Create text node
5. Append text node to `p` (text node is current working value)
6. Assign current working value to `newTodo`.

And then you go on to insert `newTodo`, which is a text node, into the document.

Breaking it up like this would get you what you want:

```
var newTodo = document.createElement('li');
newTodo
  .appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
  .appendChild(document.createTextNode(task));
```

Comment: Interesting. I assumed that the `appendChild` method would return a copy of the the node tree structure after being modified:

`li` -> `li > p` -> `li > p { task }`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.createElement('li')
```

returns a li element

```
document.createElement('li')
  .appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
```

returns a p element

```
document.createElement('li')
  .appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
  .appendChild(document.createTextNode(task))
```

returns a text node

So you are actually appending a text node.