# Cannot get content from template

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, html5-template

In Javascript, I am trying to dynamically create an HTML `<template>` element, append an `<h1>` element as its child, clone the template's contents, and then append the template to the document body.

The problem is when I access the `content` property of the template it just returns `#document-fragment`.

Here's the code:

```
var temp = document.createElement('template');
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
h1.textContent = 'hello';

var div = document.createElement('div').appendChild(h1)
temp.appendChild(div)

console.log('temp: ', temp)
console.log('temp content: ', temp.content)

var c = document.importNode(temp.content, true)
document.body.appendChild(c)
```

And here is the output for the `console.log's`:

[image: Template output]

What am I doing wrong here? Why is the template's contents showing up as empty?

Comment: The `div` is "stripped away" because the `appendChild` function returns the child element (`h1`) not the parent (`div`).

Comment: @Titus ah ok. I thought I was appending the child to the `div` and then the `div` was returned. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a `<template>`, you should append DOM content (with `appendChild()`) to the `.content` property (which is a DocumentFragment), not to the element itself.

```js
var temp = document.createElement('template');
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
h1.textContent = 'hello';

var div = document.createElement('div')
div.appendChild(h1)

//append DOM to .content
temp.content.appendChild(div)

console.log('temp: ', temp)
console.log('temp content: ', temp.content)

var c = document.importNode(temp.content, true)
document.body.appendChild(c)
```

An alternative is to add a HTML string via the `innerHTML` property.

```
temp.innerHTML = '<div><h1>Hello</h1></div>'
```

Comment: Thank you.  The `.content` property was what I was missing.  This was my issue when I was constructing a table with `document.createElement()` and `appendChild()` - easy detail to miss.

Answer (score 0):

Note, `var div = document.createElement('div').appendChild(h1)` sets `div` variable to `h1`, the appended element, not `div` element; see [What is the behavior of document.createElement when passed as an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443945/what-is-the-behavior-of-document-createelement-when-passed-as-an-argument/43443979#43443979).

Set `.innerHTML` of `<template>` to `.outerHTML` of `div` element, call `.appendChild()` chained to `document.body` with `temp.content` as parameter.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var temp = document.createElement('template');
  var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.textContent = 'hello';

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.appendChild(h1);
  temp.innerHTML = div.outerHTML;

  console.log('temp: ', temp.content);

  document.body.appendChild(temp.content);

}
```

```html
<body></body>
```